# Update Google Calendar- Insert/ Delete events

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api

I need help to create a new event inside Google calendar. I followed this [link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet)

and its working fine but now I need to add new event and delete event(existing/new)  and I couldn't able to figure out how to add events. I tried this example to insert new events in calendar:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310152/google-calendar-api-adding-an-event-to-someones-calendar-just-by-knowing-their)

but when i compile it gives me an error and here is the screen shot.

[image] I will really appreciate help.

Comment: Have you tried the help on [deleting](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete) and [inserting](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) events?

Comment: @lan I tried inserting events but its giving me an error. It says:       Message[Insufficient Permission] Location [-] Reason[InsufficientPermissions] Domain[global]

Comment: Even I changed scopes fromCalendarReadOnly --> Calendar but still getting error about insufficient permissions.

Comment: This is useful information to add to your question to show people you've tried more things.  Your question will get more attention if you can show you've tried more.  Please update the question.

Comment: Thanks @lan I updated my question.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49145935/error-while-adding-event-to-google-calendar-insufficient-permission

Comment: @lan Nope. Did not work for me.

Comment: Is there anyone who can suggest me how should I insert new event in the Google Calendar?

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: I got the solution. Now I can send invites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add new event and send invite:

```
    Event myEvent = new Event
        {
            Summary = "Discussion on new project",
            Location = "Mentor",
            Start = new EventDateTime()
            {
                DateTime = new DateTime(2018, 8, 16, 10, 0, 0),
                TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
            },
            End = new EventDateTime()
            {
                DateTime = new DateTime(2018, 8, 16, 11, 30, 0),
                TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
            },
            Recurrence = new String[] { "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO"},
            Attendees = new List<EventAttendee>()
  {
    new EventAttendee() { Email = "abc@gmail.com" }
  }
        };

 var recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(myEvent, "primary");
        recurringEvent.SendNotifications = true;
        recurringEvent.Execute();
```